# Sql query to get bounce rate based on session id and datetime

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have table with 3 columns- Url of Page Visited, User Session ID and Datetime.
Based on this information we have generate result with 2 columns - Date (unique) and Bounce Rate.

It is very clear that we need to look for single occurrences of session id, if there are 2 entries for same session id it means the user hitted the another page and didn't bounced but one entry means it bounced.

I can not write a sql query for this. I tried grouping data by session id and date but couldn't get the result in required format.

Can anyone do this?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the number of sessions with only one page per day, you can use aggregation:

```
select dte,
       avg( (num_pages = 1)::int ) as bounce_rate
from (select sessionid, min(datetime)::date as dte, count(*) as num_pages
      from t
      group by sessionid
     ) t
group by dte;
```